# TabError в python

Tags: python, discord.py

TabError. Вот код:

```py
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

move = ['!move']
cake = ['!cake']

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    rand = random.randrange(3, 13)
    if msg in move:
        work_timer = {}
        try:
            if message.content.startswith('!move'):
                work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
                
                work_timer[message.chat.id] = time.time()
                if work_timer[message.chat.id] - work_time <= 60:
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Ты сможешь использовать эту команду через 1 минуту")
                    return
            else:
                if rand == 3:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 9 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 4:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 12 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 5:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 15 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 6:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 18 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 7:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 21 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 8:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 24 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 9:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 27 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 10:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 30 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 11:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 33 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 12:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 36 единиц голода.')
                if rand == 13:
                    await message.channel.send('Вы смогли переместиться на' + ' ' + str(rand) + ' ' + 'клеток вперёд! Но вы потеряли 39 единиц голода.')
        except:
            pass    
@client.event
async def on_message2(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in cake:
        await message.channel.send('С днём рождения Шниленд! Вам выдан бесплатный приз в виде 10 единиц Голода')

client.run('censored')

Вот ошибка:

   C:\Users\77715>"C:\Users\77715\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.py"
  File "C:\Users\77715\Desktop\Discord Bot\bot.py", line 19
    work_time = work_timer[message.author.id]
                                            ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabError означает, что у Вас неверно поставлены отступы или пробелы, это Python и у него много придирок к этому. Поищите внимательнее неправильный отступ, так-как сам протестировать я не могу, за неимением токена.

Comment: Попробуйте закинуть на сервис по отформатированию кода Python, должно спасти ситуацию